# View Filesystem Access in Real Time on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, filesystems, monitoring

Had a sysinternals tool (filemon) for that, but now I can find something similar for the mac.

I'm a developer and I basically want to debug "file not found" or "wrong permissions" errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `lsof` or `fs_usage` in Terminal.  `lsof` can be quite powerful.  If it's about a specific process, you can try sampling it in Activity Monitor.

For a GUI tool, my recommendation is [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start):

[image]

[image]

[image]

More GUI-oriented utilities, which I haven't used:

[FileMon](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/FileMon.shtml)

[image]

[FS Spy](http://mac.majorgeeks.com/download5596.html)

[image]

Comment: +1 very nice answer. Btw, I've just tried FileMon and the filtering doesn't seem to work, which makes it pretty useless. fseventer is very nice.

Comment: fseventer claims "10.10 Yosemite is classified as unsupported till further notice". is there an updated answer? are there new recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

### Less visual

https://diigo.com/0xcp0 for highlights from [Brendan's blog » Top 10 DTrace scripts for Mac OS X](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) (2011-10-10).

### More visual

For more modern operating systems that are incompatible with fseventer, there's Apple [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) **Instruments** –

[image: selecting the File Activity template]

[image: Instruments in the background, Terminal in front]

– powerful, but (compared to fseventer) in some cases, Instruments may be too heavyweight.

Answer (score 4):

For viewing what files are accessed in real time you can leverage `fs_usage` part of the FSEvents feature in Mac OS X or even `dtrace` itself.

Usage: `sudo fs_usage [PID]`.

For more info, check out the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html)

Comment: fs_usage is my favorite.  I wrote about it on my blog post @ http://mohit.io/blog/fs_usage-trace-file-system-calls-on-mac-os-x/ where I was stuck with Outlook that had hung and I wanted to know what it was doing on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dtrace opensnoop](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) script to identify failed opens (file not found and permission errors)