# Mac OS X - detect file system read

Tags: macos, filesystems

I want to know what files a specific application is trying to access on my disk. I know that you can use `fs_usage`, but this outputs events from all applications. I know that you can target a single application, but only one that is already running. I want to detect all readfile-events an application is trying to do, ever since it is started. I don't want to miss out on any event.

How do you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one of the utilities in [my answer to this other SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/97980/view-filesystem-access-in-real-time-on-mac-os-x/98033#98033) will be of help.

Comment: FileMon seems to have the functionalities I desire. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that fs_usage applies to running processes. You can leave the list empty, and it will track all, also future ones.
So `sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys | grep "myprogramname" | tee logfile`
and then start "myprogramname". When done, Ctrl+C and the logfile (and stdout) has all the info.