# Is there a way to list files added/removed/modified during application installation in Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-yosemite

In Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, how can I list all files that were added, removed, or modified during an application installation?

One thought is to snapshot the drive before and after, or another is to list recently added, removed or modified files. Or perhaps it’s possible to inspect Time Machine diffs.

Comment: the perfect software is called fseventer http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start it works great on Mavericks, but I noticed that its unsupported in Yosemite.  Not sure if it will work properly.  You can give it a try.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/997722/84988

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a decent question. I don’t believe there is a simple answer. Maybe cloning the drive before and after would glean some clues? Barring that, I think maybe using [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) would help? Something like this; proof of concept:

```
find ~ -type f -cmin -30 | more
```

That command specifically would use `find` to search for any item in your home directory (`~`) that is a file (`-type f`) that has been created in the last 30 minutes (`-cmin -30`). The output of `find` is piped to `more` for easy reading, but you could also send the results to a file for later review like this:

```
find ~ -type f -cmin -30 >> find_file.txt
```

Now of course this is far from perfect for a per application review of what has been installed. Not to mention that for the purposes outlined in the question, the directory path of `~` would have to be expanded to cover the whole drive with `/` like this:

```
find / -type f -cmin -30 >> find_file.txt
```

But at least this gives you something to start with. Perhaps do a scan like this before the software install and the after the software install, diff the documents and take it from there? Run this `find` command before you install software:

```
find / -type f -cmin -30 >> find_file_before.txt
```

Then run this `find` command after you install software:

```
find / -type f -cmin -30 >> find_file_after.txt
```

Then just diff those two files.

Of course you can experiment with changing the `-cmin -30` to something smaller like `-cmin -10` or even longer like `-cmin -60` but that depends on your goals. And of course your life would be made easier by filtering out some caches/ephemeral files that just get created/trashed by the system in normal use. But then again, focusing on what exactly you would want to ignore from a `find` connected to a software install is up to you to explore and refine.